# WSL2 Kubernetes - How to mount local folder with specifying user/group rights

Tags: docker, kubernetes, file-permissions, wsl-2, persistent-volumes

I am using WSL2 Debian and Docker Desktop and I want to persist my volume data within a local folder (a path to OneDrive in best case).

This works fine but with one exception, everything is owned by `root:root`. How can I specify the `user/group` permissions within the volume?

And is there any documentation for this anywhere?

```yaml
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: dummy-service
  labels:
    app: dummy-service
spec:
  replicas: 3
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: dummy-service
  strategy:
    type: RollingUpdate
    rollingUpdate:
      maxUnavailable: 1
      maxSurge: 1
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: dummy-service
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: dotnet
          image: alpine
          imagePullPolicy: Always
          resources:
            requests:
              cpu: "100m"
              memory: "40Mi"
            limits:
              memory: "64Mi"
          ports:
            - containerPort: 5000
          volumeMounts:
            - mountPath: "/app/wwwroot"
              name: dummy-volume
          readinessProbe:
            httpGet:
              path: /heartbeat
              port: 5000
              scheme: HTTP
            initialDelaySeconds: 5
            timeoutSeconds: 1
            periodSeconds: 15
          livenessProbe:
            httpGet:
              path: /heartbeat
              port: 5000
              scheme: HTTP
            failureThreshold: 3
            initialDelaySeconds: 10
            periodSeconds: 15
            successThreshold: 1
            timeoutSeconds: 1
      volumes:
        - name: dummy-volume
          persistentVolumeClaim:
            claimName: dummy-pvc
---
apiVersion: storage.k8s.io/v1
kind: StorageClass
metadata:
  name: dummy-sc
provisioner: kubernetes.io/no-provisioner
volumeBindingMode: WaitForFirstConsumer
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolume
metadata:
  name: dummy-pv
spec:
  capacity:
    storage: 512Mi
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteMany
  persistentVolumeReclaimPolicy: Retain
  storageClassName: dummy-sc
  local:
    path: /run/desktop/mnt/host/c/Users/Markus/OneDrive/Workspace/Volume/Web
  nodeAffinity:
    required:
      nodeSelectorTerms:
        - matchExpressions:
            - key: kubernetes.io/hostname
              operator: In
              values:
                - docker-desktop
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
metadata:
  name: dummy-pvc
spec:
  storageClassName: dummy-sc
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteMany
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: 512Mi
```

Comment: Hello @Dark. Have you considered using `SecurityContext`? [This doc](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/security-context/#configure-volume-permission-and-ownership-change-policy-for-pods) shows how it could be done. Please let me know if that suits your use case.

Comment: Yes I tried it but it does not work with local-storage

Answer (score 0):

I can think of three possible solutions for this issue:

1. You could use the [Init Containers](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/pods/init-containers/). This way the container in a pod which is running as a non-root user can have permissions for the mounted volume. See the example below:

---

```
initContainers:
- name: set-permissions
  image: <image_name>
  # Give user id 555 permissions for the mounted volume
  command:
  - chown
  - -R
  - 555:555
  - /var/lib/data
  volumeMounts:
  - name: data
    mountPath: /var/lib/data
```

---

2. Another way to give the non-root user an access to the folder where it wants to read and write data is to follow the steps below:

- Create user group and assign group ID in Dockerfile.
- Create user with user ID and add to the group in Dockerfile.
- Change ownership recursively for the folders the user process wants to read/write.
- Add the following lines into your Deployment's Pod spec:

---

```
spec:
  securityContext:
    runAsUser: 1099
    runAsGroup: 1099
    fsGroup: 1099
```

---

As [described in the docs](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/security-context/#set-the-security-context-for-a-pod):

- `runAsUser`: Specifies that for any Containers in the Pod, all processes run with user ID `1099`.
- `runAsGroup`: Specifies the primary group ID of `1099` for all processes within any containers of the Pod. If this field is omitted, the primary group ID of the containers will be `root(0)`. Any files created will also be owned by user `1099` and group `1099` when `runAsGroup` is specified.
- `fsGroup`: Specifies the owner of any volume attached will be owner by group ID `1099`.

3. [Configure volume permission and ownership change policy for Pods](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/security-context/#configure-volume-permission-and-ownership-change-policy-for-pods) (I know it does not suit your use case but I will leave this option here for other community members).